# Japanese characters not printing in pdf

Tags: jasper-reports, export-to-pdf

I have added the classpath and the encoding as well. The japanese character appears in the viewer but not pdf. I have attached the xml here. Any comments as to why this is occuring?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="report2" pageWidth="288" pageHeight="216" columnWidth="288" leftMargin="0" rightMargin="0" topMargin="0" bottomMargin="0" uuid="b926edac-0470-4326-98b2-af9429e84085">
    <title>
        <band height="79" splitType="Stretch">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="43" y="22" width="97" height="20" uuid="9dc279eb-5339-468e-842b-ae7f13ab9847"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font pdfFontName="HeiseiKakuGo-W5" pdfEncoding="UniJIS-UCS2-H" isPdfEmbedded="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[2015年1月]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </title>
</jasperReport>
```

Comment: How about to change isPdfEmbedded="false"?

Comment: @dnaik Are you using the [Font Extensions](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/fonts/) mechanism?

Comment: Font extension and extensive iText-asian.jar did the trick. Thanks Alex